# Is it possible to see the RAM delta of a multi_index table operation, or see who is currently paying for a row in a table

Tags: smart-contract, ram, multi-index, contract-development

My question is in the context of smart contract development, so I'm looking for solutions that work within smart contracts:

1st: Is is possible to see the RAM delta of either an individual multi_table operation, or perhaps the current running total of RAM deltas at a certain point. For emplacing new rows this could obviously be calculated by hand because you know the size and who will pay for it, but for modifying/ erasing rows this depends on who previously paid for the row, and in the case of erasing it also depends on whether this is the last row in a scope, and if it is, it depends on who previously paid for the scope.

2nd: Is it possible to get who is currently paying for a table row and for the table scope.

These two things are obviously related, because if one of them is possible, the other one could also be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Bloks.io-Raw](https://bloks.io/transaction/afe1d6e17fff8117a9e8c30da5ba59d3effa41e800aea3896a0a7df2999f751b?tab=raw)

here: [Bloks.io-RAM-Deltas](https://bloks.io/transaction/afe1d6e17fff8117a9e8c30da5ba59d3effa41e800aea3896a0a7df2999f751b?tab=ram-deltas)

and here: [Bloks.io-RAM-Explorer](https://bloks.io/account/prospectorsc#ram)

You can also fetch all this data and more on your own using [dfuse-api](https://www.dfuse.io/en)

From what I know you can't get the data from within a contract.